# How to add external plugins in storybook 7

Tags: storybook

I have trouble to integrate plugins in storybook 7 (vuejs vite and typscript).

In storybook 6 a have my preview.js file where i import the plugins on this way:

```
import { Parameters, Decorators, app } from '@storybook/vue3';

import Vue3Lottie from 'vue3-lottie';
app.use(Vue3Lottie);

// import Flickity Slider JS
import Flickity from 'flickity';
app.component('flickity', Flickity);
//import 'flickity/dist/flickity.css';

// import Swiffy Slider JS
import Swiffyslider from 'swiffy-slider';
app.component('swiffy-slider', Swiffyslider);
```

It seems that this is not the correct way in new storybook 7

The preview.ts looks at the moment so:

```
import type { Preview } from '@storybook/vue3'
import { themes } from '@storybook/theming';

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i
      }
    },
    darkMode: {
      // Override the default dark theme
      light: { ...themes.normal, appBg: 'white', brandImage: '/img/logo-company/logo-sb-brand.svg'},
      // Override the default light theme
      dark: { ...themes.dark, appBg: '#333333', brandImage: '/img/logo-company/logo-sb-brand-light.svg' }
    }
  }
}

export default preview
```

Any ideas how to setup the file? Have i missed something?

Thanks for your help!